# Discord.PY Help Command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Ok, so I'm having an issue with my bot. I know what it is, but I don't know what the string to fix it is.
Basically I have it set to store config and prefixes and such in a json but the help command which is loading one of my commands multiple times.

I've checked the help command and i don't think that's it. Because after redoing my setprefix command (which is being displayed multiple times) it added yet another one on so now it's even worse.

Here is my storage system that I believe to be causing the issue.

```
with open("./config/config.json", "r") as configjsonFile:
    configData = json.load(configjsonFile)
    login_token = configData["discordtoken"]


with open("./config/prefixes.json") as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
default_prefix = "-"

def prefix(client, message):
    id = message.guild.id
    return prefixes.get(id, default_prefix)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.command(name="setprefix", aliases=["Prefix", "prefix"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def setprefix(ctx, new_prefix):
    """Change the server prefix for the bot.
    Alt     : Prefix, prefix
    Usage   : prefix <custom prefix>"""
    prefixes[ctx.message.guild.id] = new_prefix
    with open("./config/prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)



    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x4a3d9a, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_author(name=f"{client.user.name}", icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name="Success", value=f"Successfully changed prefix changed to `{new_prefix}`")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=client.user.avatar_url)
    embed.set_footer(text="NewHorizon Development | https://newhorizon-development.netlify.app", icon_url=client.user.avatar_url)
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=4)
```

and here is my custom help command just in case I'm wrong about what is causing the issue.

```
@commands.command(name="help", aliases=["Help", "H", "h"])
    @commands.has_permissions(add_reactions=True, embed_links=True)
    async def help(self, ctx, *cog):
        """Gets all cogs and commands.
        Alt     : h, H, Help
        Usage   : [h]elp <cog or command>"""
        try:
            if not cog:
                """Cog listing.  What more?"""
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Cog Listing and Uncatergorized Commands',
                                     description='Use `help <cog>` to find out more about them!\n(BTW, the Cog Name Must Be in Title Case, Just Like this Sentence.)')
                cogs_desc = ''
                for x in self.client.cogs:
                    cogs_desc += ('{} - {}'.format(x, self.client.cogs[x].__doc__) + '\n')
                embed.add_field(name='Cogs', value=cogs_desc[0:len(cogs_desc) - 1], inline=False)
                cmds_desc = ''
                for y in self.client.walk_commands():
                    if not y.cog_name and not y.hidden:
                        cmds_desc += ('{} - {}'.format(y.name, y.help) + '\n')
                embed.add_field(name='Uncatergorized Commands', value=cmds_desc[0:len(cmds_desc) - 1], inline=False)
                await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji='✉')
                await ctx.message.author.send('', embed=embed)
            else:
                """Helps me remind you if you pass too many args."""
                if len(cog) > 1:
                    embed = discord.Embed(title='Error!', description='That is way too many cogs!', color=discord.Color.red())
                    await ctx.message.author.send('', embed=embed)
                else:
                    """Command listing within a cog."""
                    found = False
                    for x in self.client.cogs:
                        for y in cog:
                            if x == y:
                                embed = discord.Embed(title=cog[0] + ' Command Listing', description=self.client.cogs[cog[0]].__doc__)
                                for c in self.client.get_cog(y).get_commands():
                                    if not c.hidden:
                                        embed.add_field(name=c.name, value=c.help, inline=False)
                                found = True
                    if not found:
                        """Reminds you if that cog doesn't exist."""
                        embed = discord.Embed(title='Error!', description='How do you even use "' + cog[0] + '"?', color=discord.Color.red())
                    else:
                        await ctx.message.add_reaction(emoji='✉')
                    await ctx.message.author.send('', embed=embed)
        except:
            await ctx.send("Excuse me, I can't send embeds.")
```

I am using the rewrite branch if it helps. And my setprefix command IS NOT in a cog, unlike the rest of my commands. Thus why they appear a slight bit different.

Now I'm ASSUMING my issue is that the json are not closing, which I need to know how to make them close, but if that's not the issue, I would very much appreciate someone helping me figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: The file automatically closes when using the `with open(...` context manager. What error are you getting, what's actually wrong with the help command?

Comment: it putting the setprefix command multiple times in the embed. it has it listed 3 times now in the same embed. Basically my setprefix command is uncategorized but the command is being displayed as if it were multiple copies of the same command.